# Looking for Blueprint XML namespace references. (Migrating from Spring XML.)

Tags: spring, osgi, apache-karaf, blueprint-osgi

I'm upgrading all our services to use the latest Fuse 7 / Karaf libs,

and I see that none of our Spring application contexts (`<beans>...</beans>` XML) are supported anymore.   I need to switch everything to Blueprint's `<blueprint>...</blueprint>`.

For the most part, I can copy-paste.  But I can't easily find the new Blueprint OSGi XSD/schema namespaces.

Is there a list somewhere, or an easier way than rummaging through github?

------------EDIT:

Here's an example.

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:int="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration"
    xmlns:int-file="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/file"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:camel="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="
         http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
         http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
         http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring 
         http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring/camel-spring.xsd
         http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration
         http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/spring-integration.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/file
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/file/spring-integration-file.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd

         ">
```

In `<blueprint>`, what would I change this to?

Answer (score 0):

The Blueprint XML Schema is available at https://osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0/blueprint.xsd.

Comment: Hi BJ, I've got that one.  I'm rather looking for all the other namespaces, for all the Spring tags that have a new blueprint XSD, instead of the old Spring XSD.  eg. cxf / camel-cxf / jms / jaxws, etc.  http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/blueprint/jaxws.xsd instead of http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/jaxws.xsd etc.